# Determine which .dll (.tlb) running

Tags: vb.net, vba, dll, vb6

My .exe contain a lot `dlls` added through reference or as .`CreateObject` .

I wonder is there any way when i open some `dll` to find in processes or somewhere else which .`dll` is currently in use

Comment: VB.NET IsNot vba AndAlso IsNot vb6.  Please read [ask] AndAlso take the [Tour]

Comment: Plutonix. What if i told you all those dlls contained in .exe are developed with .net and Vb6 development tool ?

Comment: In your case it doesn't matter what they're created with/what language they're created in... What matters is the language you are using/want to use in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) from sysinternals by truning on `View->Lower Pane View->DLLs (Ctrl+D)` and then clicking on your application process in processes list.

With `Find->Find Handle or DLL (Ctrl+F)` you can search for DLLs and other files being open by any system process, e.g. when you need to delete a data files but the OS refuses for file being in use reason and not telling you which one the culprit is.